# Managing Mendeley citations in Word without... Mendeley

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, citations, bibliography, mendeley

I have been given a Microsoft Word (docx) file, and has a bunch of references internally. If I try to edit the references, they become grayed out and it seems there are no options to manage, edit, or change them:

[image]

By toggling the field codes, it seems as though the references were imported by someone else using Mendeley:

[image]

I do not have Mendeley, nor do I have any desire to start using it. Is there a way to manage these citations without having to resort to using Mendeley? For example, perahps there is a way to export the Mendeley citations to an open (preferable) or other Word-friendly format, and use that instead? But maybe there is a better way altogether.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't used MS Word in ~15 years, so it's very possible I don't know something really basic. Please feel free to point this out to me!

Comment: I think what you need is to just copy, and then Paste Special, As Text, so they will lose they referenc-y style, and become editable text for you to do whatever you want to it

Answer (score 0):

References in Word are always a touchy subject because Word does a lot of unexpected things with them.

I think what you're looking for here, and may work for you is to make everything text.

To do it, you select all the references, and on the HOME tab select the drop down on Paste (Paste Special) and select "Text Only" in the list displayed.

[image: paste special word]

This way, the references will be eliminated from your document and will be pasted as Text that you can edit and form in any way you want.